# Yajra DataTables orderColumn on eloquent doesn't work

Tags: laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I'm using Yajra DataTables on my Laravel 7 project. I have a problem on orderColumn API. Here my code:

```
return Datatables::eloquent(Company::query())
        ->orderColumn('name', '`column` $1')
        ->make();
```

But the generated query is:

```
select * from `companies` where `companies`.`deleted_at` is null order by `id` asc limit 10 offset 0
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know its too late but i just face this problem too and fix this with this code

```
return Datatables::eloquent(Company::query())
    ->order(funtion($q){
        $q->orderBy('colName', 'desc');
    })
    ->toJson();
```

hope this can helpfull